# flot x2axes date layout not align with x1axis

Tags: jquery, flot

The  x2axis date does not align with x1axis time.
x2axis label is date in MM-dd format, this should align with the time set in x1axis which is an hour.. 
but this one is showing in 8:00, this should be in 00:00

```
var plot = $.plot('#divPlaceholder', [
    { label: itemKey[0], data: itemValue[0], color: '#4bb2c5' },
    { label: itemKey[1], data: itemValue[1], color: '#c5b47f' }
], {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        position: "top",
        min: minVal,  // this is current day - 24 hours
        max: maxVal,   // this is current date + 1 hours
        timeformat: tickFormat,
        tickSize: interval,
        twelveHourClock: true,
        zoomRange: [0.1, 10]
    },
    x2axis:{
        show:true,
        mode:'time',
        position:'top',
        timeformat:'%b-%d',
        tickSize: [1, 'day'],
        axisLabel: 'Lab Results',
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 16,
        axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif",
        axisLabelPadding: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        panRange:[-10, 100]
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        backgroundColor: 'gray'
    },
    zoom: {
        interactive: false
    }
});
```

[image: x2axis date not align with x1axis time]

Comment: What happens if you change %b-%d to %b-%d-%H, i.e. adding hours?  In other words, are you sure those x2axis ticks are really on 00:00?

Comment: if i set the x2 to %b-%d %H, it also displays 8:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see 8:00 when adding %H, then they're lining up correctly; it's just that in one you truncate the hours when producing the label.  If you want them to line up on the date exactly, then you need to ensure that the timestamps are all at 00:00.

Check out the discussion of [time series data](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) in the docs and search for other StackOverflow questions about times and timezones in Flot.